# CodeIgniter : Forgot password ( unable to send email and change password )

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, passwords

So, I have a problem when I try to update new random password into database and send it into client email address.

this is my model :

```
        function check_email($email)
        {
                $this->db->select('email');
                $this->db->from('user');
                $this->db->where('email', $email);
                $this->db->limit(1);

                $query = $this->db->get();

                if($query->num_rows() == 1)
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return FALSE;
                }
        }

        function reset($new, $id)
        {
                $data = array(
                        'password'=> $new
                        );
                $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
                $query = $this->db->update('user', $data);

                if($query)
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return FALSE;
                }
        }
```

this is my controller :

```
        public function lupa()
        {

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                {
                        echo validation_errors(); 
                }
                else
                {
                        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                        $id = $session_data['user_id'];
                        $email = $this->input->post('email');
                        $result = $this->password_model->check_email($email);

                        if($result)
                        {
                                $new = $this->generate_password(6);
                                $query = $this->password_model->reset(md5($new), $id);

                                if($query)
                                {
                                        $this->load->library('email');

                                        $this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'Your name');
                                        $this->email->to('admin@gmail.com');     
                                        $this->email->subject('Password reset');
                                        $this->email->message('You have requested the new password, Here is you new password:'. $new);  
                                        $this->email->send();

                                        redirect('login', 'refresh');

                                }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo 'email tidak ada di database';
                        }
                }
        }


        public function generate_password( $length = 8 ) 
        {
                $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?";
                $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
                return $password;
        }
```

and this is my view :

```
            <?=form_open_multipart('change_password/lupa');?>


                 <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
              </div>
              </form>
```

I got no error, but the new random password unable to save into my database, and why I didn't get the email ?

Did I write wrong code ?

Thanks for your attention guys :)

Comment: here   `$this->email->to('admin@gmail.com');` should be verified email, does'n it?

Comment: @splash58 : that is just example one, even with correct email, I can not send it

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913796/how-do-i-test-if-my-mysql-update-query-was-successful-in-code-igniter about update

Comment: about mail - does it work on real server?

Comment: @splash58 : I got 0 affected rows, for email should I try it on web server ?

Comment: 0 - test coonection, db sructure.... get string ( http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=update_string#CI_DB_driver::update_string) and try it in phpmyadmin. As for email, if you run it on denwer, wamp and etc, mail not sent

Comment: @splash58 : I already successfully update the password, So I will test the email in web server, thanks mate